# Amazon MWS API does PartialUpdate Require all XML Elements

Tags: xml, amazon-mws

I'm trying to update just the description of an item.

This is my Request:

```
    <AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amznenvelope.xsd">
                    <Header>
                        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
                        <MerchantIdentifier>ABCDEFGH</MerchantIdentifier>
                    </Header>
    <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
           <PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace>
                  <Message>
                       <MessageID>1</MessageID>
                       <OperationType>PartialUpdate</OperationType>
                       <Product>
                           <SKU>my_sku</SKU>
                           <StandardProductID>
                               <Type>ASIN</Type>
                               <Value>B009XXXXX</Value>
                           </StandardProductID>
                           <Condition>
                               <ConditionType>New</ConditionType>
                               <ConditionNote>New</ConditionNote>
                           </Condition>
                           <Description>My Description</Description>
                       </Product>
                   </Message>
    </AmazonEnvelope>
```

Amazon's response:

```
                <DocumentVersion>1.02</DocumentVersion>
                <MerchantIdentifier>M_MyCompany</MerchantIdentifier>
        </Header>
        <MessageType>ProcessingReport</MessageType>
        <Message>
                <MessageID>1</MessageID>
                <ProcessingReport>
                        <DocumentTransactionID>5551401111</DocumentTransactionID>
                        <StatusCode>Complete</StatusCode>
                        <ProcessingSummary>
                                <MessagesProcessed>1</MessagesProcessed>
                                <MessagesSuccessful>0</MessagesSuccessful>
                                <MessagesWithError>1</MessagesWithError>
                                <MessagesWithWarning>0</MessagesWithWarning>
                        </ProcessingSummary>
                        <Result>
                                <MessageID>1</MessageID>
                                <ResultCode>Error</ResultCode>
                                <ResultMessageCode>5000</ResultMessageCode>
                                <ResultDescription>XML Parsing Error at Line 20, Column 33: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element &apos;Description&apos;. One of &apos;{Rebate, ItemPackageQuantity, NumberOfItems, LiquidVolume, DescriptionData, PromoTag, DiscoveryData, ProductData, ShippedByFreight, EnhancedImageURL, Amazon-Vendor-Only, Amazon-Only, RegisteredParameter}&apos; is expected.</ResultDescription>
                                <AdditionalInfo>
                                        <SKU>my_sku</SKU>
                                </AdditionalInfo>
                        </Result>
                </ProcessingReport>
```

This seems to be saying that I need to provide all the elements? Even though I just want to update the description.

Answer (score 3):

The response is telling you all the fields that *could* appear in the place where it found "Description." You do not have to include all info when doing a partial update. The minimum data required is SKU and DescriptionData/Title.

The issue is that Description has to go inside a DescriptionData tag and a title is required, like below:

```
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amznenvelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>ABCDEFGH</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
    <PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace>
    <Message>
      <MessageID>1</MessageID>
      <OperationType>PartialUpdate</OperationType>
      <Product>
          <SKU>my_sku</SKU>
          <StandardProductID>
              <Type>ASIN</Type>
              <Value>B009XXXXX</Value>
          </StandardProductID>
          <Condition>
              <ConditionType>New</ConditionType>
          </Condition>
          <DescriptionData>
              <Title>Title should go here. It is required.</Title>
              <Description>My Description</Description>
          </DescriptionData>
      </Product>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```